# There is no libphp*.so in my apache modules directory

Tags: php, apache

In my apache modules, there is no `libphp5.so` in it:

```
[root@localhost modules]# ls
httpd.exp               mod_cache.so                mod_logio.so           mod_reqtimeout.so
mod_access_compat.so    mod_cache_socache.so        mod_lua.so             mod_request.so
mod_actions.so          mod_cgid.so                 mod_macro.so           mod_rewrite.so
mod_alias.so            mod_dav_fs.so               mod_mime_magic.so      mod_sed.so
mod_allowmethods.so     mod_dav.so                  mod_mime.so            mod_session_cookie.so
mod_auth_basic.so       mod_dbd.so                  mod_mpm_event.so       mod_session_dbd.so
mod_auth_digest.so      mod_deflate.so              mod_mpm_prefork.so     mod_session.so
mod_auth_form.so        mod_dir.so                  mod_mpm_worker.so      mod_setenvif.so
mod_authn_anon.so       mod_dumpio.so               mod_negotiation.so     mod_slotmem_shm.so
mod_authn_core.so       mod_env.so                  mod_proxy_ajp.so       mod_socache_dbm.so
mod_authn_dbd.so        mod_expires.so              mod_proxy_balancer.so  mod_socache_memcache.so
mod_authn_dbm.so        mod_ext_filter.so           mod_proxy_connect.so   mod_socache_redis.so
mod_authn_file.so       mod_file_cache.so           mod_proxy_express.so   mod_socache_shmcb.so
mod_authn_socache.so    mod_filter.so               mod_proxy_fcgi.so      mod_speling.so
mod_authz_core.so       mod_headers.so              mod_proxy_fdpass.so    mod_ssl.so
mod_authz_dbd.so        mod_http2.so                mod_proxy_ftp.so       mod_status.so
mod_authz_dbm.so        mod_include.so              mod_proxy_hcheck.so    mod_substitute.so
mod_authz_groupfile.so  mod_info.so                 mod_proxy_http.so      mod_unique_id.so
mod_authz_host.so       mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so  mod_proxy_scgi.so      mod_unixd.so
mod_authz_owner.so      mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so  mod_proxy.so           mod_userdir.so
mod_authz_user.so       mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so   mod_proxy_uwsgi.so     mod_version.so
mod_autoindex.so        mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so   mod_proxy_wstunnel.so  mod_vhost_alias.so
mod_buffer.so           mod_log_config.so           mod_ratelimit.so       mod_watchdog.so
mod_cache_disk.so       mod_log_debug.so            mod_remoteip.so
[root@localhost modules]# pwd
/www/server/apache/modules
```

there is no `libphp5.so` in my `/www/server/apache/modules`. who can tell me how can I init it?

in my apache httpd.conf:

```
#EnableMMAP off
#EnableSendfile on
#LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
```

so there I can not open the `LoadModule php5_module  modules/libphp5.so`.

---

**EDIT-01**

My System is CentOS 7.2.

I tried:

[root@localhost ~]# yum install -y  libapache2-mod-php5
已加载插件：fastestmirror
base                                                     | 3.6 kB     00:00
epel/x86_64/metalink                                     | 6.2 kB     00:00
epel                                                     | 4.7 kB     00:00
extras                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00
(1/2): epel/x86_64/updateinfo                              | 1.0 MB   00:05
(2/2): epel/x86_64/primary_db                              | 6.7 MB   00:07
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.sunnyvision.com
 * epel: mirror.pregi.net
 * extras: mirror.sunnyvision.com
 * updates: repo.virtualhosting.hk
No packages available: libapache2-mod-php5
Error：no need any processing

Answer (score 0):

Try this `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5` or something similar if you have different linux distributive.